# How can you find an item in a list by its index in the Visual Studio Code code editor?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

**My basic question:**

I want to find an easy way to go to where an item of a list is declared based on it's index certain index.
Preferably without executing the code.

For example if I had a list:

```
var myList = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    // ...
]
```

Would it be possible to jump to where item 16, or any index I choose, is declared in that list within the editor?

---

**My specific circumstance:**

I basically have a list of function objects called l. It is written in the code in the following format:

```
const l = [function(e, t, i) {
    var n = i(5)
      , r = i(14)
    // ... (more code here)
}
, function(e, t) {
    // ...
}
, // ... (many more items in list)
]
```

*Just to clarify, I did not write the code, nor do I intend to change it's function or the methods it uses. I just want to have a good way of navigating it.*

Whenever one of these functions are called, they are mentioned by their index. (The `i` function calls the functions from the list. e.g. `i(14)` calls the 14th function) This makes it really hard to tell which function is being called. That is why I would like an easy way to find the 14th function in the list.

Although VSCode's breadcrumbs feature displays a list of all items, it doesn't provide any indexing.

[Image Of Breadcrums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj7o6.png)

You would think that there would be some easy way of searching for a specific item by how far down it appears in the dropdown menu or some way of using "Go To Definition" to find a certain item of a list.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  But, most people find their function _by name_.  Any reason not to explicitly name your functions in your source code? e.g. `func1`, `func2`, ... etc.  Then you can find the string `func14`.  You could also insert a comment with a uniquely identifying mark that is searchable. e.g. `/*fn-14*/`

Comment: this looks like a minified code, find the original source code, nobody has written it like this, even the original author would get lost after a few months

Comment: the functions are now nameless, just give them a name like `fn000`, `fn001`, you can do this with the extension **Regex Text Generator** (generator expression `fn{{=i:size(3)}}` , add a the space at the start of the string)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the "**[VSCode-Jump](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sharonrolel.vscode-jump)**" extension: Open the Extensions view in
   Visual Studio Code (**Ctrl+Shift+X**) and search for "VSCode-Jump"
   extension. Install and activate it. Navigate to the desired list:
   Open the file containing the list of functions in your Visual Studio
   Code editor.
2. Use the "**Go to Definition**" feature: Place your cursor on the index
   you want to find, such as i(14), and **press F12**. This will take you
   to the definition of the function being called.
3. If you prefer using breadcrumbs for navigation, you can enable them
   by going to "**View" -> "Appearance" -> "Show Breadcrumbs**". This will
   also provide  you list of functions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: if you don't give the Marketplace URL or the full name we don't find the correct extension

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sharonrolel.vscode-jump

hope it helps

Comment: looked at the source code but did not have the impression that it is helpful for this question, the README is also very short, it sets a few decorated regions based on the key pressed